# Visual Studio 2017 Signing in situation

Tags: visual-studio

[image: The error that I am getting]

I was using Visual Studio Community 2017 for making 2D and 3D games with Unity3d.  When my 30-day trial expired it says sign in to your Microsoft account to use VS 2017 for free. When I am trying to sign in to VS Community 2017 to use VS 2017 for free, this error appears. What can I do?

I am using Windows 8.1 with latest updates.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate in a VS support forum.